# Foursquare Api - Unable to print json data

Tags: arrays, json, reactjs, redux, foursquare

I am building a basic search app with foursquare API using react redux. I am receiving json data but when I try to print address, photos, tips. I am getting an error "Not found" where as I can see everything in console.log

Action.js

```
    export const fetchVenues = (place, location) => dispatch => {
  fetch(`https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?near=${location}&query=${place}&limit=10&client_id=${api_id}&client_secret=${api_key}&v=20180323`)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => dispatch({ type: SEARCH_VENUES, payload: data.response.venues}))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
}

export const fetchVenueDetail = (venueId) => dispatch => {
  fetch(`https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/${venueId}?client_id=${api_id}&client_secret=${api_key}&v=20180323`)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => dispatch({ type: FETCH_VENUE, payload: data.response.venue })
    )
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
}
```

Reducer.js

```
    const initialState = {
  venues: [],
  venue: {}
}

const venueReducer = (state= initialState, action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case SEARCH_VENUES:
      return {
        ...state, venues: action.payload
      }  

    case FETCH_VENUE:
      return {
        ...state, venue: action.payload
      }
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Sidebar.js

```
<aside className="sidebar tips-sidebar">
        <h3>Tips</h3>
        <ul className="sidebar__list">
          {venue.tips.count}
            <li className="sidebar__listItem">
              <Link to="#" className="sidebar__listItemLink">
                <div className="left">
                  <img src="/image/background.jpg" alt="Tips" className="tips-image" />
                </div>
                <div className="right">
                  <h4>Arzu sendag</h4>
                  <p>guzei mekan cok serdim.</p>
                </div>
              </Link>
            </li>

        </ul>
        <Link to="#" className="allTips">All Tips</Link>
      </aside>;
```

So my problem is I am receiving the JSON but when I am trying to print address, tips, photos or contact as they are an object. I am receiving the "not found" error.

[image]

So i need help for accessing tips, photos object from foursquare venue detail api request.

{Venue.tips} Screenshoot

[image]

{Venue.tips.count} Screenshot

[image]

Comment: What is the exact error?

Comment: And where in your code are you trying to print?

Comment: I am trying to access tips like this {venue.tips} so it's working. But when I try to go inside tips object like this {venue.tips.count} I am getting an error count not found.

Comment: And `{venue.tips}` works?

Comment: yep, its gives me the object containing count and groups  array

Comment: Can you show me a screenshot of the error please?

Comment: Added screenshots

Comment: Are you sure `venue.tips` works?

Comment: Yes Colin thats the screenshot I took from sidebar components where I am feeding venue details as props venueTips. So when i do {venueTips.tips} I get the second screenshot but when I do {venueTips.tips.count} I get the error

Comment: So, to clarify: `{venue.tips}` will actually **render** to the screen?

Comment: so, If i try to render {venue.tips} I get this error "Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {count, groups}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead". But in console log I can see as per the 2nd screenshot

Comment: I dunno, it's too hard to debug like this. If you make a CodeSandbox example I'll fix it for you.

Comment: https://github.com/montygoldy/hipolabs.Code is here if u want to see

Comment: No, I want to see a CodeSandbox example.

Comment: The github repo is not public. Make it public or share the code on CodeSandbox.

Comment: here is the sandbox link https://codesandbox.io/s/744262rlwj.

Comment: here is the sandbox link https://codesandbox.io/s/744262rlwj.  Please go to /venues page and then search for "cafe" and "toronto". Will receive first 10 results and if you click on any item it will take you to details page. Over here I want tips

Comment: I can't get the codesandbox to do anything; the probably is most likely what Denys has mentioned; `venue` starts out as undefined before the request completes, hence the first `undefined` when it prints to the console before you see the `{count: 1, groups: Array(1)}` on the next line

Comment: Thanks @tony for looking into. Whats the workaround I am still receiving the same error. The problem is any object inside the json data throwing that same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting this error because `tips` in `venue` object is `undefined` until request is done. So, you should add check if `tips` property is exists in a `venue` object.

For example in your **RenderSidebar** component:

```
case "tips":

    // check if tips is exists in venueTips object
    // else make it empty to avoid error
    const { tips = {} } = venueTips

    template = <aside className="sidebar tips-sidebar">
        <h3>Tips</h3>
        <ul className="sidebar__list">
          {tips.count}
          <li className="sidebar__listItem">
            <Link to="#" className="sidebar__listItemLink">
              <div className="left">
                <img src="/image/background.jpg" alt="Tips" className="tips-image" />
              </div>
              <div className="right">
                <h4>Arzu sendag</h4>
                <p>guzei mekan cok serdim.</p>
              </div>
            </Link>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <Link to="#" className="allTips">
          All Tips
        </Link>
      </aside>;
    break;
```

Please notice, that `Sidebar` component not always take `venueTips` object so it's better to use it in a particular `case`.

In future, for instance, you can handle `isLoading` state in reducer, and display loading until tips is ready and check this boolean instead of `tips` property. It's up to you.

Also, don't use `componentWillMount` lifecycle hook for asynchronous operations. Use `componentDidMount` instead.
So, request in `ComponentDetails` component should be like this:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchVenueDetail(this.props.match.params.id);
}
```

Read the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillmount) for more details. Also, [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/vq2kqn9r7y) is working example.

Comment: Hey man It's not working as per your example. I am trying but still, that error persists.

Comment: @MontyGoldy I've updated sandbox, https://codesandbox.io/s/vq2kqn9r7y. Seems that I've just copied yours before. Check out line 66. It should work as expected.

Comment: Is there any better approach I want to access all objects inside json data. Each object have same error Do I have to check for each n every object

Comment: yes, or you can do it in render like so:

`{ venueTips.tips && venueTips.tips.count }`
`{ venueTips.anotherObj && venueTips.anotherObj.property }`

Notice that you should do it in a particular `case `clause, because as I told before `venueTips` is not passed to every Sidebar component.

Comment: Another workaround - change your `initialState` in `venueReducer` and make more deeper object if you know which properties should be. Like this: 
`const initialState = {
  venues: [],
  venue: {
    tips: {},
    anotherParam: {}
  }
}`

Comment: I am gonna try the second approach. Big thanks man for the help

Comment: @MontyGoldy in your case I'd prefer to extend your reducer with initial values, so you don't need to check every time each param until you have more nested object.

Comment: Hi denys could you please help me out with this error https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50011403/react-redux-not-dispatching-action?noredirect=1#comment87040077_50011403