# React/Redux Unable to keep previous state of search input

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am trying to save recent searches in local storage.

Reducer.js

```
const initialState = {
  venues: [],
  searches: [],
};

const venueReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case RECENT_SEARCHES:
      return {
        ...state,
        searches: [
          ...state,
          { near: action.payload.location, query: action.payload.place },
        ],
      };
  }
};
```

Action.js

```
export const fetchVenues = (place, location) => dispatch => {
  dispatch({ type: FETCH_VENUE_REQUESTED })
  dispatch({ type: RECENT_SEARCHES, payload: { place, location } })
};
```

Right now I am getting the user input and saving it to the searches array in reducer but it's not keeping the previous state. Only shows the current user input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you spread the searches, you need to do:

```
[ ...state.searches,
```

Instead of just:

```
[ ...state,
```

As that will put `state.venues (Array)` and `state.searches (Array)` in your `state.searches`

Comment: thank you tony. Big thumbs up. Will accept your answer in 10 mins. And Tony it will of great help if you could help out me on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49970320/foursquare-api-unable-to-print-json-data/49975559?noredirect=1#comment86994685_49975559