# React/Redux - Not dispatching action

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am new to react redux. I am trying to build a simple restaurant app with foursquare api. I have two actions which makes api calls to 1st. search the restaurant and 2nd one to fetch details like this.

Action.js

```
export const fetchVenueDetail = venueId => dispatch => {
  console.log("dispatching");
  dispatch({ type: FETCH_VENUE_REQUESTED });
  fetch(
    `https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/${venueId}? 
     client_id=${api_id}&client_secret=${api_key}&v=20180422`
  )
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => dispatch({ type: FETCH_VENUE, payload: 
     data.response.venue }))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
};
```

Here is my component

```
class VenueDetail extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchVenueDetail(this.props.match.params.id);
  }
  render() {
    console.log(this.props);
    const { venue, isLoading } = this.props;
    console.log("This text", venue);
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <Header type="venueDetail" venueDetail={venue} />
        <main className="main-content">
          <section className="venue">
            { !isLoading ? <ImageList venueDetail={venue} /> : <Loader /> }
          </section>
          <div className="sidebar-wrapper">
            <Sidebar type="tips" venueDetail={venue} />
          </div>
        </main>
      </React.Fragment>
    )
  }
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  venue: state.venueReducer.venue,
  isLoading: state.venueReducer.isLoading
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {fetchVenueDetail})(VenueDetail);
```

After testing I figured out it is not dispatching the action that's why I am receiving an empty response.

Here is the working sandbox code If anyone wants to check- https://codesandbox.io/s/7m4153p1jq

Comment: Looks like there's an error in the sandbox.

Comment: Your first action `dispatch({ type: FETCH_VENUE_REQUESTED })` has no payload

Comment: @jacob Yes thats the error I am getting when I click on the venues I receive after first action to get the details of the venue.

Comment: @andrew That action is just for checking isLoading. I dont know what to add in the payload thats why i left it as it is.

Comment: @MontyGoldy, it's not recognizing your redux devtools on the sandbox. That's the issue with that piece

Comment: @JacobW Is it the actual problem or only with sandbox?

Comment: Only the sandbox

Comment: @JacobW I have tested in the devtools as well no action is dispatched when I am clicking on an item. Am I missing anything in the code?

Comment: Can you make a simpler example?

Comment: @Colin Just check the components/venueDetail page. Its unable to send dispatch as per redux devtools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual problem, that you're getting error before your request starts in `Sidebar` component. There is no groups property in your `venue` object until your request is done.

If you add such check in your `"tips"` case it should run well:

```
const itemTips = venueTips.tips.groups ? venueTips.tips.groups[0].items : [];
```

You can add `groups` to your reducer and check for `length` property or choose another way, like wrapping all of the component, including `Sidebar` component, and display `Loader` instead of them. Something like this:

**VenueDetail.js**

```
{
    (!isLoading && venue.id) ?
        <React.Fragment>
            <section className="venue">
                <ImageList venueDetail={venue}/>
            </section>
            <div className="sidebar-wrapper">
                <Sidebar type="tips" venueDetail={venue}/>
            </div>
        </React.Fragment> : <Loader/>
}
```

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/xjj70z9z9w) is updated codesandbox.

Answer (score 0):

Ok So the problem was I was dispatching my action inside componentDidMount lifecycle but when i changed it back to componentWillMount. It works. Can somebody explain why?